Swap Memory Usage
Newbie to macOS and was running into some memory issues.  I've tried restarting my mac, which reset memory back to normal levels, but within 2-3 days swap and compressed memory fill up very quickly and I am forced to close applications or my macbook will crash. I haven't been running anything too memory intensive, probably just around 30-40 tabs on Firefox and a couple projects in Intellij.  Any tips of how to troubleshoot and get to the culprit?


Do you close Firefox at any time? I have my machine showing uptime of 31 days and it has no memory issues (it does have 24gb) but I close programs. Also have you considered using bookmarks instead of keeping tabs open? this may help your memory issue.

Any tips of how to troubleshoot and get to the culprit?
You're already looking at Activity Monitor, which should show you the memory used by each process. You can group them together 'hierarchically' in the View menu, to show you all the process under each application.
I'm guessing that "a couple of projects in IntelliJ" are likely to use a lot of memory.
30 or 40 tabs in a browser is probably also not insignificant -- though at least you're not using Chrome.
